# CakePHP - creating an API for my cakephp app

Tags: php, api, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have created a fully functional CakePHP web application. Now, i wanna get it to the next level and make my app more "opened". Thus i want to create an RESTful API. In the CakePHP docs,i found this link (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html) which describes the way to make your app RESTful. I added in the routes.php the the two lines needed,as noted at the top of the link,and now i want to test it.
I have an UsersController.php controller,where there is a function add(),which adds new users to databases. But when i try to browse under mydomain.com/users.json (even with HTTP POST),this returns me the webpage,and not a json formatted page,as i was expecting .

Now i think that i have done something wrong or i have not understood something correctly. What's actually happening,can you help me a bit around here?

Thank you in advace!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to parse JSON extensions. So in your **routes.php** file add:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

So a URL like http://example.com/news/index you can now access like http://example.com/news/index.json.

To actually return JSON though, you need to amend your controller methods. You need to set a `_serialize` key in your action, so your news controller could look like this:

```
<?php
class NewsController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $news = $this->paginate('News');
        $this->set('news', $news);
        $this->set('_serialize', array('news'));
    }
}
```

That’s the basics. For POST requests, you’ll want to use the `RequestHandler` component. Add it to your controller:

```
<?php
class NewsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'RequestHandler',
        ...
    );
```

And then you can check if an incoming request used the **.json** file extension:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->extension == 'json') {
        // JSON request
    } else {
        // do things as normal
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i start to get the point of APIs in CakePHP. I added in my function the if statement where it checks the extension,i added also the component in my controller. But how can i handle the JSON data so that for example the user is created?

Comment: You just call `$this->News->save($this->request->data)` as normal, but instead of redirecting with a flash message, assign the flash message to the `_serialize` view variable.

Comment: OK,thanks again! And do i have to create a view or something,or this is just it?

Comment: No. As long as you set something for `_serialize` and the visitor has requested a URL with **.json** on the end, then CakePHP will know to spit the value of `_serialize` as a JSON response.

Comment: hmmm ok. What matters me is that it always returns a "500 Internal error",on each *.json POST request :/

Comment: Try checking the error log at **app/tmp/logs/error.log**. Towards the bottom there should be a fatal error which will be the cause of your 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: i'll try and if there isn't any luck there,i would open a new thread here! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Testing for `if ($this->request->params['ext'] == 'json') { // JSON request } else { // do things as normal }` works for me. `$this->RequestHandler->extension` was always `null`. Tested on CakePHP 2.6.3. Do you know what might be wrong?!

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Not sure. The answer’s a couple of years old so something may have changed between what was the stable version of CakePHP 2.x then, and version 2.6.3.